# Code first convention not creating join table on a many to many relationship in entity framework 6.2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, many-to-many, code-first

I have entities named YogaProfile, YogaSpace, and YogaSpaceEvent
they are all .one-to-many (ex. YogaProfile->YogaSpace->YogaSpaceEvent)
Think of it like a student to a classroom to a classroom event.

FYI - I'm using EF6.2, not 7

I want to create a many-to-many relationship between YogaProfile and YogaSpaceEvent. ex. a student can be registered for many class events and a class event can have many students. I'm following these links [here](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/many-many-relationship-entity-framework/) and [here](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx) for code first many-to-many implementations

but when I run add-migration the migration file doesn't contain any join table (ex. YogaProfileYogaSpaceEvent) and when I update the database, still there's no join table.

Here is what my migration file looks like for the up

```
public override void Up()
    {
        AddColumn("dbo.YogaSpaceEvents", "YogaProfile_YogaProfileId", c => c.Int());
        AddColumn("dbo.YogaProfiles", "YogaSpaceEvent_YogaSpaceEventId", c => c.Int());
        CreateIndex("dbo.YogaSpaceEvents", "YogaProfile_YogaProfileId");
        CreateIndex("dbo.YogaProfiles", "YogaSpaceEvent_YogaSpaceEventId");
        AddForeignKey("dbo.YogaSpaceEvents", "YogaProfile_YogaProfileId", "dbo.YogaProfiles", "YogaProfileId");
        AddForeignKey("dbo.YogaProfiles", "YogaSpaceEvent_YogaSpaceEventId", "dbo.YogaSpaceEvents", "YogaSpaceEventId");
    }
```

and here is what I'm doing on the entities YogaProfile and YogaSpaceEvent

```
public class YogaProfile {
  public YogaProfile() {
      YogaSpaceEvents = new List<YogaSpaceEvent>();
  }
  public virtual ICollection<YogaSpaceEvent> YogaSpaceEvents { get; set; }
}

public class YogaSpaceEvents {
   public YogaSpaceEvents() {
      RegsiteredStudents = new List<YogaProfile>();
   }
   public virtual ICollection<YogaProfile> RegisteredStudents { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You must have PrimaryKeys on your entities, so do you have but not showing in the question?

Comment: I have a key attribute set for both the id's of each of the two entities 'YogaProfileId' and 'YogaSpaceEventId'. Is that what you mean?

Comment: In the code you provided there is no ID properties. I mean you did you remove them for simplicity? When I use EF 6.2 and add the code you provided add them Id properties and run `Add-Migration` join table is created

Comment: ya I left out lots of the code but both id's in both entities have the primary key as the id. ex. YogaProfileId and YogaSpaceEventId

Comment: The question does not contain enough details to reproduce. In EF every detail is important. Do you have fluent configuration? If yes, show it. Also make sure the sample classes contains the **exact** navigation and FK properties if any. I suspect incorrect fluent configuration (that's the only way I can get something like this), but w/o actual `mcve` it's just a guess.

Comment: No fluent, just code first.

Comment: Let say it differently. The issue is **not reproducible** with the provided sample code. Create new project, add what you have posted and try to reproduce. Can you? So we. In order to help, we need [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Try HashSet instead of List:

```
public class YogaProfile {
  public YogaProfile() {
      YogaSpaceEvents = new HashSet<YogaSpaceEvent>();
  }
  public virtual int YogaProfileId{ get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<YogaSpaceEvent> YogaSpaceEvents { get; set; }
}

public class YogaSpaceEvents {
   public YogaSpaceEvents() {
      RegisteredStudents = new HashSet<YogaProfile>();
   }
   public virtual int YogaSpaceEventId { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<YogaProfile> RegisteredStudents { get; set; }
}
```

And also i suggest to use FluentApi for explicitly mapping entities.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{

    modelBuilder.Entity<YogaProfile>()
                .HasMany<Course>(s => s.YogaSpaceEvents)
                .WithMany(c => c.RegisteredStudents )
                .Map(cs =>
                        {
                            cs.MapLeftKey("YogaProfileId");
                            cs.MapRightKey("YogaSpaceEventId");
                            cs.ToTable("YogaSpaceEventsRegisteredStudents");
                        });

}
```